# Call @PostConstruct annotated method explicitly

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm writing junit tests for one of my java class. I have a **@PostConstruct** annotated method as shown below for which I want to write the unit test:

```
@PostConstruct
public void initialize() {
    try {
        logger.info("Bootstrapping Safenet Initialization");
        String hello = cryptographicController.encrypt("Hello");
        logger.info("Bootstrapping Safenet " + hello);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        logger.error("Error initializing Crypto", ex);
        throw new DataConverterException();
    }
}
```

I want to write the unit test to test the **DataConverterException**. But i'm not sure if I can explicitly call the **initialize** method from my unit test.

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by *"But i'm not sure if I can explicitly call (...)"* - why won't you just try?

Comment: @kryger I tried it before posting the question. Was getting some error so I was not sure if the error is because of calling the postConstruct explicitly or something else. I'm very new to java and spring and still in the struggling phase.

Comment: You should include the error stack trace and explain what you mean exactly  directly in your question.

Comment: @kryger sure will follow it from now . Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1:

If the bean for the java class is created in xml and context configuration is loaded, then the bean life cycle method will be called automatically.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "XX")
```

Case 2:

Bean life cycle methods `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` should be called explicitly in the unit test cases to test.

If object of test class is created like below

```
JavaClass javaClass = new JavaClass();
```

then yes, as the bean is not created, then we need to call the `initialize` method explicilty.

both the cases will allow you to test the required area,

Mocking `cryptographicController` should give you the required options

```
@Test(expected=DataConverterException.class)
public void test() {
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(cryptographicController).encrypt("Hello");
    javaClass.initialize();
}
```